# How to record video on OSX even after switching windows/app

Tags: macos, recording, screen-recording, zoom-sdk

I know we can record video using quicktime player's new screen recording, but it only records the active space ( [https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh14112/mac#:~:text=Move%20between%20spaces,Right%20or%20Left%20arrow%20key](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh14112/mac#:%7E:text=Move%20between%20spaces,Right%20or%20Left%20arrow%20key). )

I want to record a zoom call in background while I switch my space to chrome let's say and do a google search.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Spaces, try putting your Zoom app window aside a browser window so you can see them both on screen at the same time. Then in the Quicktime Player, before recording, select "record selected portion" and frame in only the Zoom app window, before clicking the record button. While the recording is going on you can still navigate/search within the separate browser window.